# Unable to view GCP Organization Policy Page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to restrict user access in Google Cloud Compute Engine, so that they will be able to create instances only from  Trusted Image Projects. For this, I am using Organization Policy according to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access#trusted_images).

But the issue is **Organization Policies Page is not found!**

Error Message:

> URL not found!
>   We couldn't find what you were looking for. Try one of the links below.
>
> > Google Developers Console Home
> >
> > Google Cloud Platform
> >
> > Google Developers

Why it is showing like this? Is this moved to some other URL?

Comment: you need resourcemanager.organizationAdmin role just to see Org policies. What org role do you have?

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening due to your project have no [Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations) which is available through a [G Suite or Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations#before-you-begin), therefore, the option is not being shown in the IAM & admin menu.

Comment: I have a VM instance in a project inside a folder which belongs to an organisation.Still the issue persists.Do i need more resources?

Comment: Which role does your user have? According to the documentation, a resourcemanager.organizationAdmin role is needed, or you could use any of the [following roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#permissions_and_roles).